# Controller method is not invoked using IP but localhost

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf, cross-domain

I am invoking a Controller method from javascript Ajax call. When I use localhost (fine only for dev) in below code, it invokes the Controller method but if I use IP address (IP is needed when code is hosted in other some other Linux box) in place of localhost, method is not invoked.

This code works as I can see call in the network tab in browser:

```
var tmpUrl = "https://localhost:<port>/method1?param1=" + value1 + "&param2="+value2;          
$('#serviceBinding').load(tmpUrl);
```

But when I use IP address in place of localhost, there is no invocation of controller method.

```
var tmpUrl = "https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:<port>/method1?param1=" + value1 + "&param2="+value2;
$('#serviceBinding').load(tmpUrl);
```

Below is the method in spring Controller.

```
@GetMapping("/method1")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
    public String method1(...
```

I do not see any error related to CORS in the browser but I see below error in the inspect section of browser

```
GET <full URL> net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to reach IP address, you don't have a HTTPS certificate for your IP address or you have an incorrect port.

Try to ping your IP address into CLI using ping or tracert commands to check if you can reach that ip address.

Also, are you able to open the full url in your browser?

Comment: My system use a proxy to connect to internet. when I remove proxy then code using IP address works. It seems that in my code I have to disable the proxy.

Comment: then you can configure your proxy to add ip address into white list or exception list. It could work without disable your proxy.